# Let $I$ be the incenter of triangle $ABC$.Prove that the circumcenter of triangle $BIC$ lies just in the middle of arc $BC$ of circumcircle of $ABC$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

> Let $I$ be the incenter of triangle $ABC$.Prove that the circumcenter of triangle $BIC$ lies just in the middle of arc $BC$ of circumcircle of $ABC$.  [image]

Since $MB=MC$ so $M$ lies on orthogonal bisector of $BC$.Now it remains to prove $MO=BO$ or $MO=CO$ (O is circumcenter of $ABC$) but how?

Comment: You need to prove $MI=MB$ instead of $MO=BO$. It's a famous result.

Comment: It's OBVIOUS that $MI=MB$ because $M$ IS the circumcenter of $BIC$.

Comment: ...Well, aren't you trying to prove $M$ is the circumcenter of $BIC$?

Comment: No,just the reverse: we do know $M$ is the circumcenter of $BIC$, we need to show it's at the middle of arc $BC$ of circumcircle of $ABC$

Comment: I recommend doing this another way: suppose the ray $AI$ intersects the circumcircle at $A,M'$. It's obvious that $M'B=M'C$, and you need to prove $M'I=M'B$.

Comment: Good,but it's not enough to show $M'I=M'B$ since this just implies that $M'$ is on orthogonal bisector  of  $IB$

Comment: Since $M'B=M'C$(Note that angle $M'AB$ is equal to angle $M'AC$), so $M'I=M'B$ implies $M'I=M'B=M'C$, which shows $M'$ is the circumcenter of triangle $BIC$.

Comment: Thank you! convinced.So how to show $M'I=M'B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the ray $AI$ intersects the circumcircle at $M′\not=A$. It's obvious that $M′B=M′C$ since $\angle M'AB=\angle M'AC $. Now we prove $M'I=MB$, so that $M'I=M'B=M'C$ and $M'$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$.
\begin{align}
\angle IBM'&=\color{red}{\angle IBC}+\color{blue}{\angle CBM'}\\
&=\color{red}{\frac 1 2\angle B}+\color{blue}{\angle CAM'}\\
&=\frac{\color{red}{\angle B}+\color{blue}{\angle A}}2\\
&=\frac 1 2(180°-\angle C)\\&=90°-\frac 1 2\angle C
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\angle IM'B=\angle AM'B=\angle ACB=\angle C
\end{align}
So $\angle M'IB=180°-\angle IBM'-\angle IM'B=90°-\frac{\angle C}2=\angle IBM'$, hence $\triangle M'IB$ is isosceles and $M'I=M'B$. Done.

Comment: Thank you Cave(+1). Please upvote: some troubled man downvoted this nice question!.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $A,I$ and $M$ are collinear, because $$\angle BAI =\frac{1}{2} \angle BAC= \angle BAM$$
Then $\angle BIM$ is a external angle in the triangle $\triangle BAI$, and his value is $\frac{B}{2}+\frac{A}{2}$.

By other hand $\angle IBM$ is the sum of $\angle IBC$ and $\angle CBM$ then his value is also $\frac{B}{2}+\frac{A}{2}$.

Finally $\triangle BIM $ is isosceles in $M$. Analogy $\triangle CIM$ is isosceles in $M$, and we conclude that $MB=MI=MC$.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo(+1).Quite right and concise!